# Whats wrong with my code? Do while and Try Catch

Tags: java, try-catch, do-while

Keep getting syntax error, insert while expression to complete do statement. It maybe something simple like curly brackets etc.

```
{
    int num = 0;
    //flag
    boolean inputOk = false;
    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);

    do {            
         try {
            System.out.println("Enter a number....");
            num =s.nextInt();

            System.out.println("you entered : " + num);
            // got here then things are good
            inputOk = true;

         } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Again please....digits only");
            // flush the scanner
            s.next();
         }

    } while (inputOk != true);
    s.close();
    System.out.println("Thank you");    
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: please check the below Solution I think { are only the problem

Comment: Please mark as answer or vote up this solution help you

Comment: You forgot to tell us which language you are using.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are missing ending curly brackets "}" for do. For Scanner it's better to use try with resource. here is working code

```
    int num = 0;
    //flag
    boolean inputOk = false;
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        do {

            try {
                System.out.println("Enter a number....");
                num = s.nextInt();

                System.out.println("you entered : " + num);
                // got here then things are good
                inputOk = true;

            } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                System.out.println("Again please....digits only");
                // flush the scanner
                s.next();

            }
        }
        while (inputOk != true);
    }
        System.out.println("Thank you");
```

Comment: In your coder you are missing ending curly brackets "}" for Do

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ending curly brackets "{" of Do I have corrected it in below code

```
     int num = 0;
    //flag
    boolean inputOk = false;
    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);

      do {

        try {
            System.out.println("Enter a number....");
            num =s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("you entered : " + num);
        // got here then things are good
        inputOk = true;

        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Again please....digits only");
            // flush the scanner
            s.next();


        }} while (inputOk != true);
        {
           s.close();
           System.out.println("Thank you");
        }
```